# Angular: Inject an opaque token

Tags: angular, angular2-opaquetoken

I try to understand how I could inject an opaque token.

For instance, I have some service MyService, and I create an opaque token for it:

```
import {OpaqueToken} from '@angular/core'; 
...
const serviceToken = new OpaqueToken('MyService');
...
providers: [
    {
        provide: serviceToken,
        useValue: 'Service value!'
    }
]
```

It's ok. But how I could inject this service into my component?

I tried to create the same instance of an Opaque Token in my component and inject it but I got an error: Error: No provider for Token MyService!

Please, you could review an example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nQwQJTYFh649VwpEhv2e?p=preview)

Comment: `constructor(@Inject(serviceToken) private token: string)`? This is covered in the DI docs: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens. Note that `OpaqueToken` was deprecated and removed.

Comment: how are you injecting service in your component ? can you show that part too ?

Comment: jonrsharpe, I use the same approach you wrote... Error: No provider for Token MyService!

Comment: I know it's deprecated, I just wanna understand an approach

Comment: It should be the same instance

Comment: Sorry, how I could use the same instancies in module and in a component?

Comment: Just export it from one place

Comment: yurzui, ok, thanks, I got the idea. The last statement: it is stupid thing to use an opaque token in root module, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, you're right)

Answer (score -1):

Conclusion: We could use the same instance of an opaque token in component. Just export it from the module and use in a component.

Comment: Or create it in a separated file. For example https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/application_tokens.ts